# how to refocus after panel closed(firefox add on )

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am forking an firefox addon  https://github.com/jixiuf/firefox-passwordmaker

with a hotkey ,it create a panel 
I want after the panel hidden ,the password field can get focus .
It seems that current show window(tab) lose focus after panel is created.
and it cannot get it back after pannel hide.

```
var windows = require("sdk/windows");
browserWindows=windows.browserWindows;
  var lastFocusedWindow;        // do not use this ,use getLastFocusedWindow()
  function getLastFocusedWindow() {
    if (lastFocusedWindow==undefined) {
      if (browserWindows.length==1) {
        lastFocusedWindow=browserWindows[0];
      }
    }
    return lastFocusedWindow;
  }

  var panel = panels.Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: scripts,
    height: 170,
    onHide: function handleHide() {

      getLastFocusedWindow().activate(); //this doesnot work 
      getLastFocusedWindow().tabs.activeTab.activate(); //this doesnot work
      tabWorkers[tabs.activeTab.id].port.emit("set-focus");//
    }
  });

self.port.on("set-focus", function() {  
  if (lastFocusedInputEl!=undefined) {
    // if last focused password field is not undefined,then auto fill it.
    lastFocusedInputEl.focus();// this doesnot work
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There's focus manager, you can use that to get most recently focused element of whole window or sub frame etc. Here's a snippet:

```
var exampleTabSelected = function(event) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var fm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/focus-manager;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIFocusManager);
        var aXULWindow = window;
        //if fm.focusedWindow == [object ChromeWindow] then it == aXULWindow
        //if fm.focusedWindow == [object XrayWrapper [object Window]] then it is aXULWindow.gBrowser.contentWindow
        //Cu.reportError(fm.focusedWindow)
        //Cu.reportError(fm.focusedWindow == aXULWindow.gBrowser.contentWindow)
        if (fm.focusedWindow == window) {
            Cu.reportError(fm.focusedElement.nodeName);
            var browserInTab = event.target.linkedBrowser;
            var aFocusedWindow = {};
            var subFocusedEl = fm.getFocusedElementForWindow(browserInTab.contentWindow, true, aFocusedWindow);
            Cu.reportError('focused of tab contents window: ' + subFocusedEl)
            Cu.reportError('subFocusedEl has caret = ' + subFocusedEl.
        }
    }, 10); //can be 1ms
}
gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener("TabSelect", exampleTabSelected, false);
```

Comment: I figure out that , if I use panel.destroy()  web page can get the focus again .